# Is there a way to delete all entries within a section?

Tags: entries, deletion, plugin-feedme

I am currently using FeedMe to import json data every night but I need to delete all entries before doing so to make sure that any orphaned entries are removed.

What is the best way to remove all entries within a section?

Comment: Can you not use the update setting for FeedMe, eg to check against a duplicate?

Comment: Update will only update and existing entry. There may be a record removed from the data I am receiving and I will need to somehow account for that and remove it within craft.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `Delete` Duplication Handling option. From the [documentation](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe#duplication-handling):

> Delete all existing entries in this section, adding only entries from
>   this feed. Be careful. Use case: Events, or when only data from the
>   current feed is required.
>
> "I want only the entries from this feed in this section."

Comment: this will only delete entries that are recognized on both endpoint and in craft right? The issue is that if the endpoint doesn't contain an entry that is still in craft I need to delete that entry in craft.

Comment: Out of interest, have you actually tried this setting? Thats exactly what this does. It deletes _every_ entry in the section you're importing to, and _only_ imports the entries in your feed. Make sense?